# Generating correct link dependencies for GHC and Makefile style builds

Tags: haskell, makefile, dependencies, ghc

I have a Haskell project where a number of executables are produced from mostly the same modules. I'm using a Makefile to enable parallel builds, and it very nearly works the way I want. Here's a stripped down version of my current Makefile, with ideas taken from http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html#using-make:

```
HFLAGS=-O3 -Wall -v0 -fno-ignore-asserts
HASKELLS=bin1 bin2 bin3 bin4 bin5 bin6 bin7 bin8 bin9

all: $(HASKELLS)

%.hi: %.o
    @:

%.hi %.o: %.hs
    ghc -c $(HFLAGS) $<

$(HASKELLS): %: %.o
    ghc --make $(HFLAGS) $@

.hsdepend: *.hs
    ghc -M -dep-makefile .hsdepend *.hs
    rm -f .hsdepend.bak

include .hsdepend
```

As you can see, I still use `ghc --make` for linking (only); this way the individual modules can be compiled in parallel, and `ghc --make` only invokes the linker.

Unfortunately this is not foolproof: A relink is triggered only for, say, **bin1** only if **bin1.o** is newer than the executable, but not if only one of the other object files has been updated. This can happen when a change is made in a module such that it results in the **.o** file being updated, but the interface of the module does not change, i.e. the **.hi** file is not touched.

One alterative solution would be to trigger a null `ghc --make` for *every* binary every time make is invoked; unfortunately, this is slow and clutters the output (I'd like to see when something was linked and when not).

`ghc -M` only generates a dependency line for each **.o** file, but none for the linked executables. The information about which **.o** files to link into which executable (given the name of the main module **binN.hs**) obviously is there, but it's not entirely clear to me if it's possible to get to it using any Makefile magic.

I can only think of a way to do what this by writing a post-processor for **.hsdepend**, but that seems excessive.

Can anyone suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be, don't bother trying to make this work.  It should work, and it would be nice if it worked, but ghc's `-M` support is currently broken (as in, it doesn't generate proper dependency rules, and omits rules for some non-Haskell files).  Actually getting this to work reliably will take a great deal of effort, and in the end will trigger more rebuilds than strictly necessary.

Furthermore, support for parallel builds has been merged into GHC, so when ghc-7.8 is released you'll be able to use plain `ghc --make` to get parallel builds.  Or you could use ghc's HEAD now.

Comment: Will it also be possible to build multiple executables using one `ghc --make`? Because I assume it won't be safe to run multiple of them in parallel when building multiple binaries from the same modules.

Comment: A single call to `ghc --make` won't build multiple binaries, but there are a few ways to work around this without too much trouble.  Probably the most useful is to make a cabal config that specifies all your common code as a library.  Or build your executables serially, but since most of the object files will be built by the first executable build the remainder will be mostly linking.